# Anyone heard of Accessibility_TLB

Tags: .net, delphi, typelib

I have been working on converting a assembly of mine to be usable through Delphi.  I was able to convert the assembly to a PAS file and call the method in my delphi application.  But i ran into a problem where my PAS file is asking for System_Windows_Forms_TLB which i was able to find and add.  But then that file uses Accessibility_TLB and i have no clue where that is?  Does anyone know wherethat is or am i doing something wrong here?  Sorry i'm not experienced at all dealing with COM's.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found out that the reason it was asking for  System_Windows_Forms_TLB and Accessibility_TLB was because i had the whole assembly set to COMVIsible instead of just the interface.  This was in turn asking for those assemblies instead of letting the GAC take care of the rest.  I removed COMVisible from the assembly and added it to just the Interface and it all worked correctly.

Answer (score 5):

The *`System_Windows_Forms_TLB`* unit comes from the *System.Windows.Forms.dll* assembly. The *`Accessibility_TLB`* unit, likewise, comes from the *Accessibility.dll* assembly. I have two copies on my system:

```
C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework>dir /a /s Accessibility.dll
 Volume in drive C is TPT60-1106
 Volume Serial Number is 148C-7498

 Directory of C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v1.1.4322

02/21/2003  10:24 AM             7,680 Accessibility.dll
               1 File(s)          7,680 bytes

 Directory of C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727

07/25/2008  12:17 PM            10,752 Accessibility.dll
               1 File(s)         10,752 bytes

     Total Files Listed:
               2 File(s)         18,432 bytes
               0 Dir(s)  49,421,320,192 bytes free
```